# Error configuring a USB device using pyvisa

Tags: python-3.x, usb, libusb, pyusb, pyvisa

So, as context, I'm writing some controller software in Python for a RTM3004 oscilloscope for laboratory use. I had it working just fine on my laptop (Win10) and the previous laboratory computer (Linux), but upon changing to a new measurement computer, I can no longer connect to the device using Pyvisa. Here is a console log of the error, which happens whenever I attempt to connect to the device via Pyvisa:

```
Python 3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  6 2021, 13:40:21) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyvisa as visa
>>> rm= visa.ResourceManager()
>>> rm.list_resources()
('ASRL1::INSTR', 'ASRL3::INSTR', 'USB0::2733::470::103028::0::INSTR')
>>> ID='USB0::2733::470::103028::0::INSTR'
>>> instr=rm.open_resource(ID)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Hbeam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 3304, in open_resource
    res.open(access_mode, open_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Hbeam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\resources\resource.py", line 297, in open
    self.session, status = self._resource_manager.open_bare_resource(
  File "C:\Users\Hbeam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 3232, in open_bare_resource
    return self.visalib.open(self.session, resource_name, access_mode, open_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Hbeam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyvisa_py\highlevel.py", line 167, in open
    sess = cls(session, resource_name, parsed, open_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Hbeam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyvisa_py\sessions.py", line 323, in __init__
    self.after_parsing()
  File "C:\Users\Hbeam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyvisa_py\usb.py", line 81, in after_parsing
    self.interface = self._intf_cls(
  File "C:\Users\Hbeam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyvisa_py\protocols\usbtmc.py", line 293, in __init__
    self.usb_dev.set_configuration()
  File "C:\Users\Hbeam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 905, in set_configuration
    self._ctx.managed_set_configuration(self, configuration)
  File "C:\Users\Hbeam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hbeam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 159, in managed_set_configuration
    self.backend.set_configuration(self.handle, cfg.bConfigurationValue)
  File "C:\Users\Hbeam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb0.py", line 509, in set_configuration
    _check(_lib.usb_set_configuration(dev_handle, config_value))
  File "C:\Users\Hbeam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb0.py", line 447, in _check
    raise USBError(errmsg, ret)
usb.core.USBError: [Errno None] b'libusb0-dll:err [set_configuration] could not set config 1: win error: The parameter is incorrect.\r\n'
```

As well as the information I get out of `pyvisa-info`:

```
Machine Details:
   Platform ID:    Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
   Processor:      Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel

Python:
   Implementation: CPython
   Executable:     c:\users\hbeam\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe
   Version:        3.9.4
   Compiler:       MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)
   Bits:           64bit
   Build:          Apr  6 2021 13:40:21 (#tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308)
   Unicode:        UCS4

PyVISA Version: 1.11.3

Backends:
   ivi:
      Version: 1.11.3 (bundled with PyVISA)
      Binary library: Not found
   py:
      Version: 0.5.2
      ASRL INSTR: Available via PySerial (3.5)
      USB INSTR: Available via PyUSB (1.1.1). Backend: libusb0
      USB RAW: Available via PyUSB (1.1.1). Backend: libusb0
      TCPIP INSTR: Available
      TCPIP SOCKET: Available
      GPIB INSTR:
         Please install linux-gpib (Linux) or gpib-ctypes (Windows, Linux) to use this resource type. Note that installing gpib-ctypes will give you access to a broader range of funcionality.
         No module named 'gpib'
```

I've been racking my brain over this for two workdays now with no solution in sight, so I thought it best to ask for help, since I'm obviously no programming genius. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried rm=visa.ResourceManager(‘@py’) ??